# Client side validation on date input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have date input where I can put 2 formates of date(mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy) I wonder how to make some client side validation for this input to allow only certains formats, and not allows to write more than 10 letters etc so it would be much more intuitive. Can I call in some way validateRegex on client side? I want to delete this ajax.

```
<p:inputText id="dateStringComp"
             value="#{bean.dateString}"
             required="true"
             validatorMessage="Bad format: mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy">
     <f:validateRegex pattern="^(\d{2}\.){1,2}\d{4}$"/>
     <p:ajax update="dateStringCompPanel"/>
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="dateStringComp"/>
```

Comment: why don't you use p:calendar component !?

Comment: because i need wird component that allows not setting day, and allows bad dates like 99.99.9999

Comment: Did you try server side validation ?

Comment: On server it works fine, anyway it allow people to write 213213123.21312321.12313123. I would like to make as much as i can intuitive system it shoudl automaticly block more lenght than 10, using only numbers etc.

Comment: Okay use f:validateLength for this purpose .. check this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-validatelength-example/

Comment: Another solution you can give this input text a mask using jQuery.

Comment: Are there any free plugin ? For commercial projects?